# Why string address still the same after modification

Tags: c#, .net

According the documentation, type `System.String` is immutable by design. So when trying to concatenate string etc we just get a reference to result string. But If it's true, why this code always returns the same address for both cases (of course, if objects wasn't moved by GC):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StringImmutabilityCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        private static unsafe void PrintAddress(string b)
        {
            var info = typeof(string).GetField("m_firstChar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            char value = (char)info.GetValue(b);
            char* buffer = &value;
            Console.WriteLine("Addres of {0} is {1}", b, (int)buffer);
        }

        static void Foo(ref string a)
        {
            a += "xxx";
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            string b = "aaaa";
            PrintAddress(b);
            Foo(ref b);
            PrintAddress(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *not* getting the address of the string here

```
char value = (char)info.GetValue(b);   // 'value' is a local var
char* buffer = &value;                 // buffer points to local var, on the stack
Console.WriteLine("Addres of {0} is {1}", b, (int)buffer);  // no it isn't
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are writing the address of the local variable `c`, which is at the same position on the stack both times.

Note that `m_firstChar` isn't the address; it *is the first char*. Internally, the code uses the *address* of the first char relative to the object to access the data, but: `m_firstChar` will report `'a'` for both cases here, since `'a'` is the first character in the string.

For real fun:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void PassThru(string b)
{
    PrintAddress(b);
}

...
PrintAddress(b);
PassThru(b);
```

Now the "address" is different *for the same string*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function to get the address of the string:

```
Func<string, int> getAddress = x =>
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (char *p = x)
        {
            return (int)p;
        }
    }
};
```

Then this can be used to see that the address changes:

```
var text = "Foo";
Console.WriteLine(getAddress(text));
text += "Bar";
Console.WriteLine(getAddress(text));
```

Mind you, the GC might move the string around as you're using it.

Comment: @leppie - Why not? Unless I think this code needs to be used outside of the method that I need it I prefer to using delegates. Keeps all the code nicely together.